# Wrap an existing variable to be the argument to a newly-typed method call in IntelliJ code editor

Tags: intellij-idea, arguments, editor

I have this:

```
this.label = label;
```

I want this:

```
this.label = Objects.requireNonNull( label );
```

Is there a shortcut way to edit such a line rather than me typing in the `Objects.requireNonNull()` followed by cut/paste or dragging the variable to inside the parentheses?

I can imagine selecting the variable (`label` in this example), then pressing some keystroke that lets me type the method call, and upon hitting Return puts that var within the parens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Surround live template

You can create a [surround live template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html#live_templates_configure).

- Surround templates wrap a block of the selected code with the text specified by the user. For example, T expands into a pair of tags, for which you can specify a name. You can also select a block of code, then press Ctrl+Alt+J to open the Select Template popup and select the T template to wrap the selection with a pair of tags.

Here is an example of creating your desired `Objects.requireNonNull`, here with abbreviated name `ornn`.

[image: screenshot of Preferences > Editor > Live Templates > Java > ornn]

To invoke your live template:

1. Select the text you want to surround.
2. Press the keystroke currently designated for live templates.

You discover that needed keystroke by looking at *Preferences/Settings > Keymap > Other > Surround with Live Template…*.

[image: screen shot of Preferences/Settings > Keymap > Other > Surround with Live Template]

That shortcut would be…

- macOS: Option + Command + J
- Windows: Control + Alt + J

## Structural Search

Another option would be to configure [Structural Search and Replace inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-work-with-structural-search-and-replace.html#custom_inspection) with the quick fix, then apply it via the Alt+Enter on the matched code.

Comment: I see a couple of live templates there such as `C` and `WL` that use `$SELECTION$`. But how does the user invoke those without wiping out the text selected in the editor?